# how to free object in c# winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, object, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i free objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406794/how-do-i-free-objects-in-c-sharp)

my problem is i am using ..

```
 video = new Video(vpath[a]);
 video1 = new Video(vpath[a + 1]);
 video2 = new Video(vpath[a - 1]);
```

to show 3 videos at same time on a winform.. and this in a function which is called by an button event ... but it consuming to much memory ...

i did this

```
 video = null;
 video1 = null;
 video2 = null;
```

but its still not helping me out ... how i can reduce the memory consumption by this 3 objects??

my question will be flagged as possible duplicate of

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406794/how-do-i-free-objects-in-c-sharp
```

but i still want to get over this thing bcoz i didn't get help from that

Comment: Well, the other thread explains it really. Call Dispose() on any objects you no longer need.

Comment: its release unmanaged resources.. will that help ??

Comment: What makes you think setting variable to null is not helping? Are you getting out of memory error or working set of the processing is increasing?

Comment: does it consume more memory when the videos are playing or after all of them have stopped?

Comment: yess the use of memory is increasing and after some time i am really getting an error of which leads to out of memory issue

Comment: @CodeIgnoto its consuming memory when the videos are loading to the application

Comment: @Mr.Steak i already mention that in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting object to null does not mean that it won't stay in memory until garbage collection will happen. You can explicitly call garbage collection (`GC.Collect()`) but this is not desirable unless you don't have another choice.

You can use `dispose` instead of forcing garbage collection.

```
class Video : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Close managed resources and etc. 
    }
}
```

And use instances of class with `using` statement. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/898867/1283847) is good answer how to use IDisposable pattern.

Comment: i don't want use `GC.Collect()` any other option ?

Comment: Please read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx before you consider using `GC.Collect()`. I would use it only I am really sure at what I want to do and there is no alternative way.

Comment: @Ekk You are completely right. I've just listed as a possible way.

Comment: ok can't i call `video.Dispose()` will this help?

Comment: @Drone after leaving `using` block `Dispose` is automatically called. of course you can call it manually to avoid `using` statements.

Comment: Ok its seems like by using `video1.Dispose()` and `video2.Dispose()` i am able to release its resources but i couldn't use `Dispose()` on `video` object bcoz only this object is used to play the video so now memory consumption is much less ..

Comment: @PLB thanks i am able to do it and maintain the memory to a certain limit.... thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

you need release the resource

```
   using (Video video = new Video(vpath[a]))
   {
    .....
   }
```

and at the end, you can use SetProcessWorkingSetSize to trim the memory it uses, see answer at here: [webbrowser control with memory increasing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199071/webbrowser-control-with-memory-increasing-problem)

Comment: Ok its seems like by using video1.Dispose() and video2.Dispose() i am able to release its resources but i couldn't use Dispose() on video object bcoz only this object is used to play the video so now memory consumption is much less

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMP to display your videos instead, that way the WMP politely handles streaming of your video instead of loading it up all at once in memory.

[How to: Embed Windows Media Player on a Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You would then just use:

```
var video1 = new Uri("c:\\somefolder\\myVideo1.avi");
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = video1.AbsoluteUri;

var video2 = new Uri("c:\\somefolder\\myVideo2.avi");
axWindowsMediaPlayer2.URL = video2.AbsoluteUri;

// and so on...
```